# Triangle in Circle Problems

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

[image]

In Fig.1 given that DE, DF & DG are respective perpendiculars to AB, AC & BC

Prove that E, F & G are collinear.

(I found this problem on youtube but on trying to solve through co-ordinate geometry, the expression becomes very complex after a few steps, is there any elegant solution!)

---

In Fig.2 given that EC & ED are tangents to the semicircle

Prove that EO is perpendicular to AB.

(I found this problem on twitter and was able to solve it through co-ordinate geometry but the steps were too long and complex. There should be an elegant solution)

Comment: See [Simson line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simson_line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fig. 1 is just related to the classical [Simson line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simson_line), whose existence depends on angle chasing.
About Fig. 2, the hint I give you is to consider the intersection of $AC$ and $BD$.
 This point $Q$ is collinear with $E$ and $O$ *and* it lies on the circle through $C,O,D$.

[image]

Since $O$ is the orthocenter of $ABQ$ the claim $EO\perp AB$ is a straightforward consequence.
You may also notice that the circle through $C,D,E$ is the nine-point circle of $ABQ$.